How do we differentiate between the unknown and the impossible?
When we think of things as impossible, we usually think of things that are contrary to current scientific knowledge, such as nothing being able to travel faster than the speed of light.
This is deemed impossible because it breaks our understanding of scientific laws. On the other hand, things like supernaturalism for example are often seen as unknown rather than impossible given that they are posited to be untestable.
However, what exactly demarcates the two, and is there philosophical literature talking about the difference? I ask because at closer glance, this boundary may seem subject to interpretation, and it may be tenable to rephrase something that is “impossible” as merely “unknown” and vice versa.
For example, one can say “perhaps there is some unknown law that allows things to travel faster than the speed of light. Thus, it is unknown if things can travel faster than the speed of light” (and in fact, some interpretations of QM do actually posit superluminal influences, atleast).
Or one can say “the causal closure principle where every physical effect always has physical causes suggests that purely “nonphysical” entities (such as god) cannot causally affect the physical world, thus according to current knowledge, this is impossible.”

We don't. Those are just two English words, and you can look them up it any English dictionary, and ask in linguistic forums if that's not enough. In philosophy, for asking a question you would need to first refer to specific writing using those words.

I don't know the answer to your question. It's impossible for me to provide an answer without  more information (ie. consult a dictionary) ;-)

From a scientific perspective these terms are just different sides of the same coin. In essence:

A particular concept is unknown when it lies outside our current knowledge, understanding, and capacities
A particular concept is impossible when our current knowledge, understanding, and capacities cannot create a context in which is manifests

For example, our current knowledge, understanding, and capacities cannot create a context in which we push an object past the speed of light, so that is pragmatically impossible. But we also recognize that we may gain knowledge, understanding, or capacities that will make it possible in the future. That's theoretically unknown. Likewise, we cannot create a lab context in which a god reliably appears before us, but someday we might learn something that allows that to happen: pragmatically impossible; theoretically unknown.
A lot of people push for a condition of theoretical impossibility — i.e., absolutely, universally, timelessly impossible under any context of any possible knowledge, understanding, and capacity — because that makes for a tidy, comforting, well-ordered universe. But (pragmatically speaking) that boils down to a good dose of wishful thinking. We don't know what we don't know, and we don't know that what we do know is complete, perfect, or unsurmountable knowledge. Such is life…

‘Time’ can intervene in the case of ‘unknown’ and can sometimes make it something 'known'.  But if something is 'impossible', it must always be impossible.  Time has no role in it.  When someone says something is impossible, he/she only means that it is currently unknown.  Instead of 'unknown' he/she used the word 'impossible' because the power of imagination is low; that's all. The power of imagination 'seems to increase' because the base for  imagination has risen from a low level over time. IMHO, the word 'impossible' should only be used if time has no role to play.

You don't know what you don't know.  In fact there are many unknowns that you don't even know about.
So, when someone says something is "impossible" what they mean is that it appears impossible from their current incomplete understanding.
This doesn't mean that certain things aren't impossible, but rather that we can't rule out the possibility that our understandings are incorrect.
